# IBotToUser implementation stops from activity logging

Tags: c#, botframework

We implemented **IBotToUser** interface to handle translations of messages sent by the bot to the user and registered it as below. The translation works fine but for some reason the bot responses are not logged in Table Storage.

```
 Builder.RegisterType<InterceptBotToUser>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
 Builder.Register(c => new InterceptBotToUserTranslator(c.Resolve<InterceptBotToUser>()))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

We are looking for both translation and activity history. As soon as we register classes to perform translation, the bot to user messages are not stored in Activities Table. If we disable translation (i.e. DI registrations), bot to user messages are logged in Activities table.

```
public sealed class InterceptBotToUser : IBotToUser
{
    private readonly IMessageActivity toBot;
    private readonly IConnectorClient client;

    public InterceptBotToUser(IMessageActivity toBot, IConnectorClient client)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.toBot, nameof(toBot), toBot);
        SetField.NotNull(out this.client, nameof(client), client);
    }

    public IMessageActivity MakeMessage()
    {
        var toBotActivity = (Activity)toBot;
        return toBotActivity.CreateReply();
    }

    public async Task PostAsync(IMessageActivity message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)message, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class InterceptBotToUserTranslator : IBotToUser
{
    private readonly IBotToUser inner;
    public InterceptBotToUserTranslator(IBotToUser inner)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.inner, nameof(inner), inner);
    }
    public IMessageActivity MakeMessage()
    {
        return inner.MakeMessage();
    }

    public async Task PostAsync(IMessageActivity message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         //TODO: Translate here
        await inner.PostAsync((Activity)message, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a comment in the Bot Builder sdk's **DialogModule** here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/31048a2173313c81a2db47efce6a8a869b4ec284/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/DialogModule.cs#L419

It states:

```
/// <see cref="LogBotToUser"/> is composed around <see cref="MapToChannelData_BotToUser"/> is composed around
/// <see cref="AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser"/>.  The complexity of registering each component is pushed to a separate
/// registration method, and each of these components are replaceable without re-registering
/// the entire adapter chain by registering a new component with the same component key.
```

This means there is no need for the **InterceptBotToUser** class.  You can have **InterceptBotToUserTranslator** replace the **LogBotToUser** with the following:

```
builder
     .RegisterType<InterceptBotToUserTranslator>()
     .Keyed<IBotToUser>(typeof(LogBotToUser));
```

Then modify the class itself so it is constructed with the **IActivityLogger** and call the logger accordingly:

```
public class InterceptBotToUserTranslator : IBotToUser
{
    private readonly IBotToUser inner;
    private readonly IActivityLogger logger;
    public InterceptBotToUserTranslator(IBotToUser inner, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.inner, nameof(inner), inner);
        SetField.NotNull(out this.logger, nameof(logger), logger);
    }
    public IMessageActivity MakeMessage()
    {
        return inner.MakeMessage();
    }

    public async Task PostAsync(IMessageActivity message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //call the logger
        await this.logger.LogAsync(message);

        //TODO: Translate here

        //post to the next IBotToUser in the chain
        await inner.PostAsync((Activity)message, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```